# Get Error 13 , Type mismatch despite all types being the same

Tags: excel, vba

My code tries to sum up values in columns 4-25  and then place the result in column 26 like this:

```
Dim Sum As Currency

Sum = 0
Debug.Print "Sum after setting it to 0 is type: " & VarType(Sum)
For j = 4 To 25
    Debug.Print "Sum in the loop before equation is: " & VarType(Sum)
    Debug.Print " Range is type: " & VarType(Range(Cells(lRow,4),Cells(lRow, 4)))
    
    Sum = Sum + Range(Cells(lRow, j), Cells(lRow, j)) ' GETS STUCK HERE
    Debug.Print "Sum after equation in the loop is: " & VarType(Sum)
Next j

Debug.Print "Sum after the loop is: " & VarType(Sum)
Range(Cells(lRow, 26), Cells(lRow, 26)) = Sum
```

The Debug.Print results are like this:

```
Sum after setting it to 0 is type: 6
Sum in the loop before equation is: 6
Range is type: 6
Sum after equation in the loop is: 6
   comment I got rid of the repetitive values from the loop
```

So all the variables seem to be of type Currency yet I get the mismatch

I should mention that the cells in the workSheet are formatted to Currency.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you
Adam

Comment: `VarType(Range(Cells(lRow,4),Cells(lRow, 4)))` - why don't you use `j` instead of `4`?

Comment: "the cells in the workSheet are formatted to Currency" - this is actually irrelevant. The format and the underlying value are separate things. Common misconception.

Comment: Also, you don't need a loop here: `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("D" & lrow & ":Y" & lrow))`

Comment: Also, `Range(Cells(lRow, j), Cells(lRow, j)` and `Range(Cells(lRow,4),Cells(lRow, 4)))` can be simplified to just `Cells(lRow, j)` and `Cells(lRow, 4)`.

Comment: Or `Range("Z" & lrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(RC[-22]:RC[-1])"`

Comment: Thank Guys, the reason for

Comment: Sorry, hit return there by mistake: The reason for VarType(Range(Cells(lRow,4),Cells(lRow, 4))) is just to see what the Type of any of the cells in range are. Thanks for the pointer on format and the underlying value, that will help in the future, thank for the tip on not needing a loop, much cleaner without it. Thanks for the great, comments, but I still don't know why I'm getting the mismatch error, any thoughts on that?

Comment: If you change the `4` to `j`, you should be able to figure out which cell is causing the error.

Comment: you could try adding `.value` after your `Range(..)`